# Limit webpage ending

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps

I have this div where I embedded a google maps with a full width and everything is perfect.

The only thing is that I want the website to end with that map, but after the map there is a big white empty space which is very annoying and i cant get rid off.

this is the white space:
[image]

This is HTML:

```
<section id="map">

            <div class="row map-responsive">


                <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3610.334763153511!2d55.25977471511042!3d25.191930738095937!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x3e5f69d635700003%3A0x5c8b6fcc676e05d2!2sEngage+Me!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sae!4v1462471068339" width="100%" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>



            </div>
    </section>
```

CSS:

```
.map-responsive{
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    top: -150px;
    padding: 30%;
    height:0;
}
.map-responsive iframe{
    left:0;
    top:0;
    height:300px;
    width:100% !important;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: Probable `padding: 30%;` should be changed to `padding: 30% 30% 10%;`

Comment: Still getting the white space... :/

Comment: You can right click on the white space and from the developer tools, identify the element that holds that extra space

Comment: Is there anything on the page below the white space? Maybe the page just ends there because it's a short page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was setting padding to 30px instead of 30%.

Also I deleted the  and just left the  on its own.